# how to decide which isolation is better while implement scripts in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have one doubt in sql server .

how to choose which isolation level is better while implement sql script.

in sql server we have isolation level are multiple are 1)read committed
2)read uncommitted3)repeatable read 4)serialzable.

can you please tell me which sistuvation  which isolation is beeter and how to tak decission 
which isolation is beeter while write scripts in sql server .

Comment: As always, it depends. Better for what? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: There's a reason that Read Committed is the default isolation level for all SQL Server databases. It depends on the situation but I'd say that you really need to have a reason to choose anything else than the default. It's a broad question which will receive subjective answers

Comment: The generic answer is "whatever the default is" because a) that's presumably why the default was selected and b) it's likely to be assumed by any script that doesn't already explicitly pick something else.